# finding the index of the string that is found within an 'if any' method

Tags: python, json, selenium, pycharm

i have two lists A and B. i want to be able to take an string from A and if it finds and matches the same string in list B I would like for that if method to then tell me the index of the matching string in list B

ive tried multiple for loops within for loops to no avail and finally I have not seen an examples on the internet that show an if any method return the index of a matching string as described above.

```
for link in range(len(SudoLinks)):  # goes through all phone models and plans permutations
    index = link

    for phone in range(len(dataRaw['devices'])):  # creates an index of phones from aPI to index
        ApiPhoneList.append(dataRaw['devices'][phone]['model'])

    if any(phonesListExtended[index] in x for x in ApiPhoneList):
        print("phone found at index: " + x.index(x))


    else:
```

Comment: Not sure why you need the `for phone` loop in side the `for link` loop. It should be as simple by getting `ApiPhones` list first and then just compare the items in `for link` loop. And Also a side note -  update the variable names `x` is little confusing which instance you are referring to :-)

Comment: The `any()` built-in function will return a boolean value. It can not return an index. If you need something other than a simple yes or no, then `any()` is not what you are looking for.

Comment: How is this question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
for link in range(len(SudoLinks)):  # goes through all phone models and plans permutations
    index = link

    for phone in range(len(dataRaw['devices'])):  # creates an index of phones from aPI to index
        ApiPhoneList.append(dataRaw['devices'][phone]['model'])

    for n, x in enumerate(ApiPhoneList):
        if phonesListExtended[index] in x:
            print("phone found at index: " + n)
```